# $\frac{a}{1+b^2c}+\frac{b}{1+c^2d}+\frac{c}{1+d^2a}+\frac{d}{1+a^2b}\geq 2$

Tags: inequality, factoring, fractions, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I am stuck in the following olympiad problem:

Suppose that $a,b,c,d\geq 0$ and $a+b+c+d=4$. Prove that
$$
\frac{a}{1+b^2c}+\frac{b}{1+c^2d}+\frac{c}{1+d^2a}+\frac{d}{1+a^2b}\geq 2.
$$

**Attempt.** I tried to use reversed AM-GM technique.
\begin{alignat}{2}
\frac{a}{1+b^2c}-a &= \frac{-ab^2c}{1+b^2c} &\qquad 
\frac{b}{1+c^2d}-b &= \frac{-bc^2d}{1+c^2d} \\
\frac{c}{1+d^2a}-c &= \frac{-cd^2a}{1+d^2a} &\qquad 
\frac{d}{1+a^2b}-d &= \frac{-da^2b}{1+a^2b}
\end{alignat}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By C-S and AM-GM we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{d}{1+a^2b}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{d^2}{d+a^2bd}\geq\frac{(a+b+c+d)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(d+a^2bd)}=$$
$$=\frac{16}{4+(ab+cd)(ad+bc)}\geq\frac{16}{4+\left(\frac{ab+bc+cd+da}{2}\right)^2}=$$
$$=\frac{16}{4+\left(\frac{(a+c)(b+d)}{2}\right)^2}\geq\frac{16}{4+\left(\frac{\left(\frac{a+c+b+d}{2}\right)^2}{2}\right)^2}=2.$$

Comment: There are typos at the 2nd and 3rd lines.  The question asks for a lower bound of the sum of fractions.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac {d}{1+a^2b}=\sum_{cyc}\frac {d^2}{d+a^2bd}$$

Hence by Titu's lemma 
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac {d^2}{d+a^2bd}\ge \frac {(a+b+c+d)^2}{\sum_{cyc} (d+a^2bd)}=$$
$$=\frac{16}{4+(ab+cd)(ad+bc)}$$

Now by AM GM inequality we have $$\frac {ab+bc+cd+ad}{2}\ge \sqrt{(ab+cd)(ad+bc)}$$ 
Hence we get 
$$\left(\frac {ab+bc+cd+ad}{2}\right) ^2\ge (ab+cd)(ad+bc)$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{16}{4+(ab+cd)(ad+bc)} \ge \frac {16}{4+\left(\frac {ab+bc+cd+ad}{2}\right)^2}$$

Now again by AM GM inequality 
$$\frac {a+b+c+d}{2}\ge \sqrt{(a+c)(d+b)}$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac {16}{4+\left(\frac {(a+c)(b+d)}{2}\right)^2}\ge \frac {16}{4+\left(\frac {\left(\frac {a+b+c+d}{2}\right)^2}{2}\right)^2}$$
$$=2.$$